# I traveled in or at the Philippines?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

"I traveled in (at) the Philippines."

I have seen many sentences that use "in" and "at" with this kind of sentence. I want to know what's the difference between the two? When to use it?

Thank you very, very much! I'm a beginner, please bear with me.

Comment: If you don't live in the Philippines and just visited there, you should say "I traveled to the Philippines". If you live there and you mean that you travelled to different places there, you should say "I travelled in the Philippines".

Comment: @Au101 I think that the reason the questioner called herself a beginner is because of her young stack account not English language experience, however, this question does seem more befitting of ELL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "at" and "in" when specifying location](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/difference-between-at-and-in-when-specifying-location)

Comment: Strange. There was no mention on the locative usages of _in_ and _at_ being not an ELU topic in the duplicate thread. Admittedly, the question was not focused on one example, but the discussion there was detailed and complex.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever preposition is used here mean completely different things,

> I travelled *at* the Philippines

Makes little sense and would not seem natural,

> I travelled *in* the Philippines

Implies that you went to the Philippines that travelled around a bit.

The other alternative is talking about travelling *to* the Philippines which has a different denotation but may be what you're looking for:

> I travelled *to* the Philippines

Implies that you went on a trip and the final destination was the Philippines.

In the end you have to choose what you mean by the sentence because each preposition changes its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

> I traveled the Philippines

which essentially means that you traveled and traversed the country. This isn't usage you can use with countries that don't begin with "The", however.

Another example, courtesy of Merriam-Webster

> We're traveling the countryside

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is actually a pretty good alternative, along the lines of _I travel the world and the seven seas_, as in the Eurythmics song.

Answer (score 0):

*At* considers a location such as the Philippines as a point on a map, like an *X*. This is similar to 'the treasure is buried at the *X*'. You can specify *X* by latitude and longitude. It is hard to conceptualize travelling at a point.

*In* speaks of *within* a location. He felt safe *within his own country*. You can travel within a location.

So the answer is *in*.